# Ref or state duplication or HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a modal component, with these props:

```
interface ModalComponentProps {
    isOpened?: boolean;
    closeCallback?: any;
}
```

I watch the prop changes with:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<ModalComponentProps>, prevState: Readonly<ModalComponentStates>, snapshot?: any) {
    if (prevProps.isOpened !== this.props.isOpened) {
        this.toggleDrawer();
    }
}
```

`closeCallback` prop is used to reset content inside the modal or to set state in the parent component when I click on close modal button.

I would like to use this component to create an addUserModalComponent component from it. I insist on the fact that I want to be able to act on the state internally (via the close modal button) AND also from the outside to open via a button elsewhere on the page so, with props. But that the problem when going up the state isClosed is that I have to do it wherever I use this component

I can use a reference to open and close by exposing public methods but it's not really React-friendly.

I also see that I could use a HOC, but it's more of an abstraction than a composition.

How would you do?

Comment: See  [React - Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) and [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: @ShivamJha Yes I have read it already, maybe my problem was not clear enough. I modify the post

Comment: If you want to avoid lifting up `isOpened` to the parent for every usage, refs are probably the best solution

Comment: @Kai Thx, I try with Hoc, it's working good, but, this is props and states duplication for me..

Comment: You could put the state in a context and wrap your entire app with it, putting the modal at the root, if you need to show it in many places. That's a pattern that I commonly see